# Debug.Print stopped working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

How can I ensure reliable use of `Debug.Print` ?

I know there have been many solutions posted for this, but none of them work. This command just keeps on being broken, sometimes it may work for a while, but generally -- it fails (see the number of SO questions regarding this). The solutions seem to vary, and yet it keeps happening - so here it is again where none of the solutions below are fixing the problem (save for installing on a fresh computer which only works for around 10 projects then fails again)

### What I have tried

*1.* Creating a new application from scratch

*2.* Using the alternative to `Debug.Print`

> System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners[0].WriteLine

*3* Checking my *app.config* which shows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

*4.* Checking my settings to see if `DEBUG` and `TRACE` are enabled (they are)
[image: debug and trace enabled]

*5.* Checking that the Immediate window is on the correct tab with [Debug] selected in the drop-down (it is)
[image: debug visible]

*6.* Ensure that I start the application in `Debug` mode (it is)
[image: debug mode started]

*7.* Removing all extensions / plugins.

*8.* Installing on a fresh computer. (works for a short period, then fails indefinitely again)

---

I have no AntiVirus or "potentially" conflicting software on my boxes where I test if this issue is consistent in bare windows, or if there may be another application causing it.

Are there certain cases (in the code itself like `async/await` etc) which consistently cause no output for `Debug.Print` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  The `Output` window doesn't contain this output even when `Debug` is selected, and my `Immediate` window disappeared.

### How to get the Immediate window back

[image: immediate window]

*Click the menu on the top **Debug -> Windows -> Immediate** or press **[CTRL]+[G]***

### The result showing it works

[image: immediate window output]

**Caveat:** Just because you have the immediate window shown while coding, doesn't mean it will be there when you enter *Start Debugging [F5]* mode, or vice-versa. It may also disappear and not be there when you restart Visual Studio or start a new application.  Just follow the directions above to make it reappear, and mind the other note below.

---

**Note** : After doing this, the window appeared as a floating window which I had to dock again.  After docking, I tried to clear it using `right-click` and instead of a context menu, Visual Studio committed suicide, and then restarted - back to the project list screen (it didn't reload my project).

Comment: Ugh, just fix the setting.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > untick the "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" option.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you !!     :)

Comment: @ Kraang Prime，glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, please mark it as the answer. So it could help other community members who meet the same issue as yours. Have a nice day!

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT - need to wait another 23 hours to mark it as the solution. Hans's suggestion is also viable.  I ended up doing both.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thank you, from 2020 also!

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me, what finally got it working again was Project Properties> Build Check Define DEBUG Constant

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One easily overlooked possibility is that the project hasn't configured any trace listeners.
Either configure one in the config file or add:

```
Debug.Listeners.Add(New DefaultTraceListener)
```

in your code.
This will cause debug output to be written to either the output window or the immediate window depending on your Debugging settings ("Redirect all output text to the immediate window").

Answer (score 0):

Also worth checking - right-click in the output window, and ensure "Program output" is checked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).